# Button is disabled until I reopen the Activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I have my main `Activity` with two `Buttons` on it. When I start the application, you can click on one `Button` and it will take you to the right `Activity`, but I can click the second `Button` a hundred times and nothing happens. It looks just like the first `Button` and changes to the usual blue color when I press it, **BUT** if I go the the first `button's` `Activity`, then go BACK to the first `Activity`, the second `Button` works. I don't understand what's going on here.

#### Main `Activity`:(Note, SignUp is the button that doesn't work):

```
public class GameNetActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    
                Button SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Welcome.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    
                    
            Button SignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Signup.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

            });
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have registered for the onClickListener for SignUp button within the onClickListener of SignIn button. Take that out and put it separately in the onCreate().

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
....
    Button SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Welcome.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });


    Button SignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Signup.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
...
...}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you! So basically, I just had to move the parentheses right?